# copy text from file to another

Tags: copy, cat, echo

I've been trying to copy the entire text of a file to another

The command that I've been using is:

`echo $(cat file1) > file2`

**file1**

```
text
text in other line
more text in other line
```

But my result have this format

**file2**

```
text text in other line
more text in other line
```

**Why this command doesn't copy the file1 exactly same in file 2??**

Comment: There's really no good reason to use a process substitution `$(...)` and `echo` here: just `cat file1 > file2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem, just use cp:

```
cp file1 file2
```

For your solution to work, just wrap the evaluation sentence in `" "`, like:

```
echo "$(cat file1)" > file2
```

This happens because using `" "` to wrap the evaluation in `$()` preserves newlines, tabs, spaces, and without them it just don't. So the problem wasn't `cat` but the `echo`

Answer (score 0):

It's sufficient to simply do `cat file1 > file2` , or use `cp` as Alejandro suggested. If you want to get creative, you can also do:

- `awk '{print $0 > "file1.txt"}' file2.txt`
- `python -c 'import sys; f1 = open(sys.argv[1],"r"); f2 = open(sys.argv[2],"w");[f2.write(l) for l in f1];f1.close();f2.close()' /etc/passwd file1`